# How to conditionally override a Python class property with a method

Tags: python, class

Is it possible to conditionally override a class property with a property method?

If I have this class which I can instantiate by passing in a dict:

```
def Foo(Object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)

    # pseudo code (this doesn't work)
    if not self.bar:
        @property
        def bar(self):
            return u"I have overridden foo's bar"
```

And I make this instance and set `bar` to `''` or `None`:

```
my_foo = Foo(**{'bar':u''})
```

and then I call the `bar` property:

```
my_foo.bar
```

and get

```
u"I have overridden foo's bar"
```

I would like to have the property method `bar` returned, instead of the `bar` value that was passed in when the object was created.

Can I do that somehow?  Any help would be awesome.

Comment: What do you mean by "have the property method returned"?  Are you saying you want `my_foo.bar` to return the empty string that you passed in, but if you did `other_foo = Foo(**{'bar': None})` then you want `other_foo.bar` to run the property?

Comment: Could you please post some sample code and expected results to illustrate your question? It's not clear at all what you are asking for.

Comment: I've tried to clarify it some more.

Comment: I think you'll have to generate the class dynamically. It could be done with `__new__`. Anyway I think it easier if, inside the property you call a private method, and you override this private method instead of the property.

Comment: @Bakuriu Would you be able to show me what you mean in an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To override a property you have to act on the class and not on the instance, because their machinery, on the instance, gets called before `__dict__` lookup and you end up with `AttributeError`s. Instead you can set a different property on the class.

But to do so you either have to modify your class every time you create an instance(which I bet you do not want), or you have to generate new classes dynamically.

For example:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self._val = val
    @property
    def val(self):
        return self._val

class SubType(Foo):
    def __new__(cls, val):
        if val % 2:
            #random condition to change the property
            subtype = type('SubFoo', (SubType,),
                           {'val': property((lambda self: self._val + 1))})
                return object.__new__(subtype)
            else:
                return object.__new__(cls)
```

And the results are:

```
>>> d = SubType(3)  #property changed
>>> d.val
4
>>> f = SubType(2)  #same property as super class
>>> f.val
2
```

I don't like much this kind of hacks. Probably the easier way of doing thing is calling a private method that computes the property value, for example:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self._val = val
    def _compute_val(self):
        return self._val
    @property
    def val(self):
        return self._compute_val()

class SubFoo(Foo):
    def _compute_val(self):
        if self._val % 2:
                return self._val + 1
        else:
                return self._val
```

Which yields the same results as before:

```
>>> d = SubFoo(3)
>>> d.val
4
>>> f = SubFoo(2)
>>> f.val
2
```

I believe this trick could be seen as an application of the Template Method design pattern, even though it is applied to properties.

Comment: Thanks, I need to go home and rethink my life.

Answer (score 0):

Python properties can't be overwritten, as doing so raises an `AttributeError`. However, you could try storing your override values and then looking them up when the property is executed:

```
def overridable(of):
    def nf(self):
        if hasattr(self, "_overrides") and of.__name__ in self._overrides:
            return self._overrides[of.__name__]
        return of(self)
    return nf


class Foo(object):
    _overrides = {}

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for k, v in kwargs.iteritems():
            try:
                setattr(self, k, v)
            except AttributeError:
                self._overrides[k] = v

    @property
    @overridable
    def bar(self):
        return u'I have overridden foo\'s bar'


my_foo = Foo(bar=3)
print my_foo.bar
```

Comment: Just made it slightly nicer with a decorator :) No more `import inspect`

Comment: "as doing do raises an `AttributeError`" - this isn't quite the whole story, and it looks like the OP has already noticed that setting `self.__dict__['bar']` will work, insofaras not raising the exception. It still doesn't set the attribute in any meaningful sense, because the machinery that calls the property's underlying method triggers earlier than a lookup into the instance `__dict__`.

Comment: @lvc is correct - you can set the `__dict__` on the object, but properties (as bound instance methods) aren't looked up in the __dict__.